# Linkit One crashed after few hours while sending post

Tags: arduino

I'm bought a Linkit One last week and I'm trying to send http post (JSON) request to my remote server via sim card from the Linkit One board.
It all seems working fine but after couple hours those request stopped arriving to my server.

this is my code :

```
#include <LGPRS.h>
#include <LGPRSClient.h>
#include <LGPRSServer.h>

char server[]   = "myserver.com";
int port        = 80;
String object   = "";
String Location = "";
int objSize;
String objLength;

LGPRSClient client;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    while (!LGPRS.attachGPRS("internet.golantelecom.net.il", "", "")) {
        delay(500);
    }
}

void loop() {
    object = "value=test";
    sendHttpRequest(object);
    delay(5000);
}

void sendHttpRequest(String object) {
    objSize          = object.length();
    objLength        = String(objSize);
    int timeOut      = 0;
    int index        = 0;
    String response  = "";

    if (client.connect(server, port)) {
        // FOR THE CONSOLE :
        Serial.println(F("POST /index.php HTTP/1.1"));
        Serial.print(F("Host: "));
        Serial.println(server);
        Serial.println(F("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
        Serial.print(F("Content-Length: "));
        Serial.println(objLength);
        Serial.println();
        Serial.println(object);
        Serial.println();

        // FOR THE SERVER :
        client.println(F("POST /index.php HTTP/1.1"));
        client.print(F("Host: "));
        client.println(server);
        client.println(F("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
        client.print(F("Content-Length: "));
        client.println(objLength);
        client.println();
        client.println(object);
        client.println();
  }
  else Serial.println("connection failed");

  while (client.connected()) {
      if (client.available() > 0) {
          char value = client.read();
          if(String(value) == "{" || index) {
              response += String(value);
              index++;
              if(String(value) == "}") index = 0;
          }
      }
      if (!client.connected() || timeOut == 35000) {
          Serial.print("Server Response: ");
          Serial.println(response);
          Serial.println();
          client.stop();
      }
      timeOut++;
   }
}
```

And this is the log from the server :
http://s11.postimg.org/f6oriqj37/image.png

Please help me to figure out what is going on here..

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A new version of LinkIt ONE SDK v1.1 was released on 2/18/2015. You can try to download the latest version of SDK from [this link](https://labs.mediatek.com/site/global/developer_tools/mediatek_linkit/sdk_intro/index.gsp), and update the firmware on the board accordingly. The companion firmware of LinkIt ONE SDK v2.0 is v1.1.05. Hope this resolves your issue.